# How do I set dhclient debug info on?

Tags: freebsd, dhcp

#### On a FreeBSD computer

- Is there a DHCP client log that I could use to debug a DHCP issue?
- Can I set a debug param to get more information from the `dhclient`?

**UPDATE #1**

I found a lead on this article [handy tools for debugging DHCP on linux](https://web.archive.org/web/20160927144154/http://bentis.calepin.co/handy-tools-for-debugging-dhcp-on-linux.html)
but that's on Linux (dhcping, dhcpdump), and I don't have these on my FreeBSD, I won't be able to install them.

**UPDATE #2**

```
$ tcpdump -lenx -i eth0 -s 1500 port bootps
```

Comment: As state in the freebsd `dhclient` there is an option to make it less verbose but none to make it more verbose. that's bad luck. http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=dhclient&sektion=8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manpage:

> It can be made to emit verbose messages  displaying  the  startup
>   sequence  events  until  it has acquired an address by supplying the
>   -v command line argument.

Type:

```
dhclient -v eth0
```

...where `eth0` is your network interface.

Comment: -v is not a valid switch on FreeBSD, but thanks.

Answer (score 6):

`dhcpdump` is the tool of your choice.

If you haven't installed it already, it's available from the FreeBSD `pkg` repository: `pkg install dhcpdump`.

Then, just use `dhcpdump -i fxp0`.

I found more information at https://linux.die.net/man/1/dhcpdump

Comment: That link redirects to some fraudulent site.

Comment: I edited the answer to fix it, @HolgerBöhnke